# Securing Personal Identifiable Information in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm struggling with how to deal with protecting some specific information while using Entity Framework. A good example is the SSN field. I'm working on an application program that allows the user to enter the SSN. The admins are allowed to search on SSN. I'm supposed to protect the SSN secure while in memory.

My solution that somewhat works is to remove the ssn field from the entity generated class, create a partial class that contains the ssn field that uses a backing property that stores the data in a securestring.

It's not perfect but it works. It has a real problem as entity is going to regenerate the SSN field on me each time someone updates the entity framework. I looked through the .tt file but I don't feel that I've got grasp on how to identify the SSN field and have it skip over re-generating it.

Is there a best practice for securing delicate information that's not passwords? Encrypting everything in the database is not a good approach for us. We often have Analyst doing direct queries against the database. If all the important information is encrypted then that would interfer with their work.

This is an MVC 5 project with Entity 6.1 in an n-Tier architecture. Also, I'm using AutoMapper to map to data transfer objects.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The first problem you have is that you are required to protect SSN "while in memory."  It has to be plain-text at sometime so this requirement is impossible to satisfy.

I would look into [Transparent Data Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) and deal with the database performance hit.  Afterall there has to be some risk/reward to using SSNs...